# Use Roboopy to copy files newer than yesterday (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, time, automation, robocopy

I'm trying to copy only new files that have been added in the last 2 days for backup

```
@ECHO OFF
robocopy D:\Auto\finished D:\Auto\backup *.* /maxage:2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
robocopy <sourcepath> <destination path> /E /XO /XN
```

/E - copies sub-directories as well as files including empty directory

/XO - exclude old files i.e. files on source that also exist at the destination but has older or same time-stamp.

/XN - exclude newer files i.e. files on source that also exist at the destination but has newer time-stamp

To see more option: use this `robocopy /?` in cmd prompt.